# Unable to Integrate Instagram in iOS App

Tags: instagram

i am unable to post my photos on instagram using ios App. I got the following code from a post here on stackoverflow but it does not work. When Instagram starts, it displays error unable to open file. kindly help me.

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]);
        [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savedImagePath];
        docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
        docController.delegate = self;
        [docController retain];
        docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
        [docController setURL:imageUrl];
        [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
    }else{

        UIAlertView *errorToShare = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instagram unavailable " message:@"You need to install Instagram in your device in order to share this image" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorToShare show];
        [errorToShare release];
    }
```

Comment: I just tested it with 612x612 jpeg image, it works fine. It does not work with png or smaller resolution

Answer (score 2):

Minimum resolution for instagram is 612x612. Always JPG.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion, the minimum resolution remains at **612x612** (this is due to displaying images on retina devices), but Instagram now supports both **JPEG** and **PNG** images. All non-square images sent to Instagram must be cropped before posting.